# Apply certain JS to specified class/IDs only

Tags: javascript, jquery, craftyjs

I have a game written in JS, and have some code to prevent
the user from dragging on and highlighting the in-game contents:

```
onSelectStart="return false;"
onMouseDown="return false;"
style="-moz-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; user-select: none;"
```

I usually apply this to the specific elements in my game individually within HTML,
but it doesn't look good when you have all this code for each element you want
"un-selectable".

Using my tiny knowledge of JavaScript, I wrote something like this:

```
$(".nonselect").Nonselectable();
function Nonselectable() {
    onSelectStart="return false;"
    onMouseDown="return false;"
    style="-moz-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; user-select: none;"
}
```

Then add `.nonselect` to those elements I want un-selectable.

But it is not working. Why does it not work, and how can I do this?

Comment: why not make it in css?

Comment: @k102 The reason why I don't do it in CSS is because the `onSelectStart` and `onMouseDown` have to be there for IE. I could ditch IE, but for now, I want to have it work for all browsers.

Comment: You can view this tutorial to make your own jQuery plugin where you can add events as well as styles to the selected elements http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Answer (score 0):

use the `each()` function

```
$(".nonselect").each(function(){
    $(this).selectstart(function(event){event.preventDefault();});
    $(this).mousedown(function(event){event.preventDefault();});
    $(this).css("-moz-user-select", "none");
    $(this).css("-khtml-user-select: none; user-select", "none;"
});
```

Comment: Sorry, the first 2 functions don't seem to work when put into `each()`.